# Semantical Error - Doctrine createQueryBuilder

Tags: sql, doctrine, symfony-2

Mas uma vez eu fico travado usando uso doctrine.

Eu queria fazer isso:

```
SELECT c.nm_computador, c.te_ip_computador, log.usuario, log.data
FROM computador c
INNER JOIN log_user_logado log ON c.id_computador = log.id_computador;
```

mas faço assim:

```
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c.nmComputador', 'c.teIpComputador', 'log.data', 'log.usuario')
        ->from('computador', 'c')
        ->innerJoin('log.idComputador', 'WITH', 'c.idComputador');
```

é acontece isso :

[Semantical Error] line 0, col 124 near '.idComputador': Error: Identification Variable log used in join path expression but was not defined before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você reproduziu na sua aplicação os relacionamentos entre as tabelas, o Doctrine já sabe que colunas usar para relacionar uma tabela com a outra. Portanto, não é necessário especificar as colunas nos JOINs de um DQL.

Assim, sua query que, em SQL, é assim:

```
SELECT c.nm_computador, c.te_ip_computador, log.usuario, log.data
FROM computador c
INNER JOIN log_user_logado log ON c.id_computador = log.id_computador;
```

... ficaria assim em DQL:

```
SELECT c, lot
FROM computador c
JOIN c.lot
```

... e assim pelo `QueryBuilder` (se eu não me engano, pois costumo usar DQL):

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->select('c', 'log')
    ->from('computador', 'c')
    ->join('c.log');
```

Comment: foi exatamente como utilzei. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim:

```
$query = $this->doctrine->getManager()
    ->createQuery('SELECT c.nmComputador, c.teIpComputador, log.data, log.usuario
                       FROM SuaBundleOndeEstaoAsEntidades:log JOIN log.idComputador c');
```